# Scala XML serialization

Tags: xml, serialization, scala

Seeing the power of Scala, I wonder if an arbitrary object graph could be serialized and deserialized to/from XML using built-in Scala language features and libraries (e.g. without XMLEncoder, XStream or JAXB). Unfortunately, I haven't found such a solution. What could you advise?

Answer (score 8):

I don't know "if an arbitrary object graph could be serialized and deserialized to/from XML using built-in Scala language features and libraries," but since there are some native support for XML in Scala, I'll mention them. More detail could be found in Ch. 26 of [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala) called Working with XML:

> This chapter introduces Scala's
>   support for XML. After discussing
>   semi-structured data in general, it
>   shows the essential functionality in
>   Scala for manipulating XML: how to
>   make nodes with XML literals, how to
>   save and load XML to files, and how to
>   take apart XML nodes using query
>   methods and pattern matching.

To quickly summarize the chapter, I'll quote some key points.

- Scala includes special support for processing XML.
- Scala lets you type in XML as a literal anywhere that an expression is valid.
- You can evaluate Scala code in the middle of of an XML literal by using curly braces ({}) as an escape.

So you can write something like:

```
val foo = <a> {3 + 4} </a>
```

The above evaluates to `scala.xml.Elem = <a> 7 </a>`.

- If you want to find a sub-element by tag name, simply call `\` with the name of the tag.
- You can do a "deep search" and look through sub-sub-elements, etc. by using `\\` instead of the `\` operator.

The book has an example of serialization and deserialization of an abstract class, but it's hand-written:

```
abstract class CCTherm {
  val description: String
  val yearMade: Int

  def toXML =
    <cctherm>
      <description>{description}</description>
      <yearMade>{yearMade}</yearMade>
    </cctherm>

  def fromXML(node: scala.xml.Node): CCTherm =
    new CCTherm {
      val description = (node \ "description").text
      val yearMade    = (node \ "yearMade").text.toInt
    }    
}
```

Also more info could be found in a draft book called [scala.xml](http://burak.emir.googlepages.com/scalaxbook.docbk.html).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I want a generic solution though, where serialization code is written only once and not in every class in order to avoid boilerplate code and information duplication.

Comment: For those that have the 2nd edition of the book, the XML chapter is the 28th.

Answer (score 4):

afaik there is no such thing. But you might want to take a look at [sbinary](http://code.google.com/p/sbinary/)

Answer (score 3):

In the package net.liftweb.json, object xml, I find the following function:

```
def toXml(json: JValue): NodeSeq = {
    def toXml(name: String, json: JValue): NodeSeq = json match {
      case JObject(fields) => new XmlNode(name, fields flatMap { f => toXml(f.name, f.value) })
      case JArray(xs) => xs flatMap { v => toXml(name, v) }
      case JField(n, v) => new XmlNode(name, toXml(n, v))
      case JInt(x) => new XmlElem(name, x.toString)
      case JDouble(x) => new XmlElem(name, x.toString)
      case JString(x) => new XmlElem(name, x)
      case JBool(x) => new XmlElem(name, x.toString)
      case JNull => new XmlElem(name, "null")
      case JNothing => Text("")
    }

    json match {
      case JField(n, v) => toXml(n, v)
      case JObject(fields) => fields flatMap { f => toXml(f.name, f.value) }
      case x => toXml("root", x)
    }
  }
```

There is an Extraction package that has functions to convert at least case classes to JSON. Together with toXml, this might convert many data types to XML.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of "advice", we've been using the native libraries for many quick-and-dirty configuration files. The major advantage is that the "parsing" code is used to add nice error messages. Like this:

```
val xml = xml.XML.load( source )

val required = ( xml \ "value" ).firstOption match {
    case None => error( "The value element is missing, or should I be a default?" )
    case Some( req ) => req
}
```

This is where I typically used something like XStream, so it wasn't a big switch. I'm not sure if you could get the error message + default handling on your deserialization framework with a library.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in Scala's native class library. But there is no shortage of Java libraries that will do this.