# Convert Scala object to XML

Tags: xml, scala

There are numerous Scala libraries to convert arbitrary objects to JSON and a few to convert JSON to XML, but I can't seem to find a nice way to convert arbitrary objects to XML. What's a good approach?

Answer (score 3):

I used [scalaxb](http://scalaxb.org) a while ago. It works very well if you have an XSD (or WSDL) as input to generate your classes. If this is the case, I also recommend using it.

Since you're also talking about JSON it may be that you have a web application using REST. In this case, have a look at [Lift's REST-Support](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-Chapter-11.html). For instance, if you use one of its internal persistency frameworks then all your entity types get a `toXML` method for free.

A third possibility would be to [write your own conversion](http://joeygibson.com/2009/09/24/im-liking-scalas-xml-literals/) using [Scala's XML literals](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/131).

Btw possible duplicates on Stack Overflow:
[Scala XML serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756317/scala-xml-serialization)
and [Which XML serialization library for Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967160/which-xml-serialization-library-for-scala)

Comment: Liftweb's toXml looks like it takes a JValue, not an arbitrary object, unless there's some part of the API that I'm missing. Re: scalaxb, I don't have schemas.

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about Lift's persistency entities with a mixed in trait [Mapper](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/#net.liftweb.mapper.Mapper).

Answer (score 1):

Check this project: https://github.com/geirolz/advxml

It's a simple library based on RuleTransformer(standard scala xml library) and Cats with the aim to simplify the XML transformation and serialization/deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

[scalaxb](http://scalaxb.org/) looks decent, I'd try that first.